# Why does my image not appear Html?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I wrote this short code but my background image does not appear at all.. it is strange because if i change for example the width and height with 'px' it is displayed

Im trying to display the background-image with the full length of the screen and to fit in the div tag
any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>My Web Page</title>

        <style>



        .hola {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('../Img/imagenes/fotoportada.jpg');
            background-size: cover;


            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="hola">

    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to your image is right? Once I see relative paths it screams wrong path to me.

Comment: Can you click on the image link from within inspect element on your browser? Does it bring up the image?

Answer (score 2):

The height of the element is specified as `100%`.

This is computed with respect to its parent element, which is `auto` (the default).

CSS defines `100%` of `auto` as `auto`, so the element is as tall as it needs to be to contain its content.

It has no content, so this is `0px`.

This gives no height to render the image in.

---

You probably want to set a `min-height` of `100%` on the element *and all its ancestors* (`body` and `html`).

Comment: Thanks.. you are right..it is about the height but setting the height as min-height: 100% didn´t worked..<br/>

body, html {
min-height:100%;
}

.hola {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('../Img/imagenes/fotoportada.jpg');
            background-size: cover;


            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

Answer (score 0):

The div will not have a width or height if it has no content and if you use percentages. A background image does not count as content.

Answer (score 0):

Just add position:absolute; 
It will work as you want

```
.hola {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url('../Img/imagenes/fotoportada.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            position:absolute;

            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you!! this worked :)   if you have 1 min. could you explain why this worked? thanks!

Comment: the position property should be there to give some command to the element as you HAVE giving width, height ,background-repeat , BY default it takes position static. which cant effect the width height and background-repeat...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
body {
    background: url('../Img/imagenes/fotoportada.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```